# How to attach an animation to an empty

Tags: animation, armature, bones, drivers

i have some keyframes on my object , and i want to control that from an empty , so that when i move the empty forward i plays the forward animation. How can i do that. I know that i must use drivers , but i don't know how to control animations with drivers . don't have to add the driver to the empty but to the object , but there isn't one single object , there are multiple of the

**This is my mesh**

[image]

**This is the armature**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an *"action"* and *"action constraint"* on the armature to do that.

[image]

With the armature selected, go to the *dope sheet*, select the *action editor* and use the *stash* button. That will remove the animation from the armature but keep it in memory for later use.

[image]

Now, enter *pose mode* in the armature, select a bone, go to the constraints part, and add an action:

[image]

Parameters for the image above:

- The empty as target with channel (X location) and location range
- The action to apply with its frame range

Once done for one bone, select them all keeping the bone that has the constraint active, then go to the *pose* menu, *constraints* then *copy constraints to selected bones*.

[image]

Back in object mode, you can now select and move the empty to trigger the animation.

[image]